# React dynamic select with button

Tags: reactjs

I have an object array that looks like this:

```
const polls = [
    {
        title = "poll1",
        options = "option1;option2;option3"
        returnAddress = "xYn38akn[...]"
    },
    {
        title = "poll2",
        options = "optionA;optionB;optionC"
        returnAddress = "nJb3enH[...]"
    },
]
```

what I want to do is based on this array of object, to add a select-element (dropdown) with the possible options and a button, that calls onSend(returnAddress, selectedOption) with the returnAddress of the corresponding poll and the selected option.

Is it possible, to dynamically create this select and button per poll, so that every select has only the possible option of the corresponding poll and the button calls the onSend method with the selected option from the select and the returnAddress of the corresponding poll?

I've managed to get it to work when there is only one poll by having a state and setting it in the select:

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('')

function handleSelectedOptionChange(event: { target: { value: React.SetStateAction<string>; }; }) { 
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
}

[...]

<Select 
  [...]
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange{handleSelectedOptionChange}
  [...]
>
```

but of course this doesn't work with multiple polls...
Sorry if that is a dumb question, it's the first thing I'm trying in React :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply start your `selectedPol` with `null` to depict `no pol selected`. And based on that once you select, you can dynamically switch between `options`.

**Here is the code that I have typed for the usecase**

**Go to https://ikqdn.csb.app/select in `Codesandbox Browser` or directly click this link to open it.**

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/App.js

*I hope this is what you require*

Comment: cool thank you, that is almost what I wanted :-) maybe I was a bit unclear so I try again: on the page, I want to list every poll with the title and a select with the option, so for example:

poll1:
select with the options for poll1

poll2:
select with the options for poll2

but all listed on the same page.

Comment: You can mark it as an answer & upvote to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);

function handleSelectedOptionChange(event: { target: { value: React.SetStateAction<string>; }; }) { 
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
}

[...]
polls.map((poll) => {
    const options = poll.options.split(';').filter(item => item.trim());
    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption[index] || undefined}
        onChange{e => handleSelectedOptionChange(e, poll.returnAddress)}
        [...]
      >
          {
            options.map(option => (
              <Option key={option}>{option}</Option>
            );
          }
      </Select>
    );
});
```